# how to override a tophorizontalmenu's superfish-modified.css file in prestashop 1.6

Tags: overriding, prestashop-1.6

I want to change top horizontal menu background color by overriding the superfish-modified.css file using override functionality of the prestashop 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

PrestaShop's documentation explain you how to do so:
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors#Overridingdefaultbehaviors-Overridingotherbehaviors

You'll see it's pretty trivial :)

Hope this helps!